# Highcharts legends data overlapping issue on set and update data

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I am having problem with my Highchart legend, when I update or set data dynamically its overlapping with existing legend items. How do I fix this??

here the update config code

```
$('#dataUpdate').bind('click', function() {
  Highcharts.charts[0].series[0].update({
            name: 'my series',
            size: '100%',
            data: [
        { name: "Jun", y: 1 },
        { name: "Jul", y: 1 },
        { name: "Aug", y: 1 },
        { name: "Sep", y: 1 },
        { name: "Nov", y: 1 },
        { name: "Dec", y: 1 },
        { name: "Jan", y: 1 },
        { name: "Feb", y: 1 },
        { name: "Oct", y: 1 }

                ]
        }, true, true); 

  });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/thanveer3983/5owcLuv7/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a regression which has been fixed already. Works fine on the master. Will be in main code after the next release.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/7qohe9zc/

```
<script src="https://github.highcharts.com/master/highcharts.src.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
<button id='dataUpdate'>Update</button>
<button id='setData'>Set data</button>
```

Issue: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/12651